# Python pandas different separators for header and data

Tags: pandas, read-csv

I wrote a nice script that parses into a pandas dataframe some monolitic output for easy plotting and manipulation.

I can read different sections of the lines and turn them into a bigger dataframe almost always

I can combine the following two:

```
  E*/MeV   224Pu     225Pu     226Pu     227Pu     228Pu     229Pu     230Pu  
    48.0 0.192E-11 0.106E-05 0.498E-05 0.354E-06 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
...
...
```

and

```
  E*/MeV   224Pu     225Pu     226Pu     227Pu     228Pu     229Pu     230Pu  
    48.0 0.192E-11 0.106E-05 0.498E-05 0.354E-06 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00

...
...
```

by making them a dataframe with some crafty one liner
`pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='latin1', sep='\s+', skip_blank_lines=True, skiprows=lambda x: x not in rows_to_keep)` once they are dataframes I can concatenate them.

HOWEVER, my problem arises when the headers suddenly also have one nasty space like bellow (notice the differce between `224Pu` and `222 U`). This last sections completely screws up my read_cvs.

```
  E*/MeV   222 U     223 U     224 U     225 U     226 U     227 U     228 U  
    48.0 0.722E-06 0.102E-03 0.306E-04 0.188E-06 0.671E-06 0.976E-06 0.977E-08
...
...
```

Is there any way where I can apply different "sep" settings for header and data?

Thank you in advance.

I tried different versions of sep, including `sep=\s{2,}` and it reads correctly the headers but now obviously it misses the data.

I do not see how adding more separators would help me as they are both spaces, or maybe I don't know enough about regexp.

Comment: Can you provide the data? Or an MRE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Looks like a fixed width file, use `read_fwf`

Comment: It is a fixed width size produced by (drum roll) fortran. I didn't know about this. I already found the answer by treating the header one way and the data in another but this is certainly worth looking into. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle headers and data separately:

```
import re

filename = 'data.csv'
with open(filename) as fp:
    while True:
        row = fp.readline().strip()
        if row:
            headers = re.split(r'\s{2,}', row)
            break
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, sep='\s+', header=None, names=headers, ...)
```

First case:

```
>>> df
   E*/MeV         224Pu     225Pu     226Pu         227Pu  228Pu  229Pu  230Pu
0    48.0  1.920000e-12  0.000001  0.000005  3.540000e-07    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

Second case:

```
>>> df
   E*/MeV         222 U     223 U     224 U         225 U         226 U         227 U         228 U
0    48.0  7.220000e-07  0.000102  0.000031  1.880000e-07  6.710000e-07  9.760000e-07  9.770000e-09
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my try:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

to_load = """  E*/MeV   222 U     223 U     224 U     225 U     226 U     227 U     228 U  
    48.0 0.722E-06 0.102E-03 0.306E-04 0.188E-06 0.671E-06 0.976E-06 0.977E-08"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(to_load), sep="\s+", skiprows=1, header=None)
columns = pd.Index(pd.read_csv(StringIO(to_load), sep="\s{2,}", nrows=1, header=None).loc[0,:])
df.columns = columns
print(df)
```

prints:

```
0  E*/MeV         222 U     223 U  ...         226 U         227 U         228 U
0    48.0  7.220000e-07  0.000102  ...  6.710000e-07  9.760000e-07  9.770000e-09
```

I thanks to skirows and nrows argument, I can read only the header column with one seperator and before the content with another.

Answer (score 1):

In his particular case, you could use spaces that are followed by a digit as separator:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tricky.csv', sep=r'\s+(?=\d)', engine='python')
```

Output:

```
   E*/MeV         222 U     223 U     224 U         225 U         226 U         227 U         228 U
0    48.0  7.220000e-07  0.000102  0.000031  1.880000e-07  6.710000e-07  9.760000e-07  9.770000e-09
```

Comment: This is probably also a valid answer but I think treating the headers separately gives the flexibility to face new unforseen formats without being a regexp guru.

Comment: @donpicoro of course, I just provided this as a handy workaround ;)